# Python List Comprehensions Create a List of Powers Understanding the Programming

Tags: python, list-comprehension

So the question is from

https://github.com/Asabeneh/30-Days-Of-Python/blob/master/13_Day_List_comprehension/13_list_comprehension.md

Using list comprehension create the following list of tuples:

```
[(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
(2, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32),
(3, 1, 3, 9, 27, 81, 243),
(4, 1, 4, 16, 64, 256, 1024),
(5, 1, 5, 25, 125, 625, 3125),
(6, 1, 6, 36, 216, 1296, 7776),
(7, 1, 7, 49, 343, 2401, 16807),
(8, 1, 8, 64, 512, 4096, 32768),
(9, 1, 9, 81, 729, 6561, 59049),
(10, 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000)]
```

The following is my solution:

```py
powers_list = [tuple([i] + [i**j for j in range(6)]) for i in range(11)]
print(powers_list)
```

This next part I got form GeeksForGeeks:

```py
matrix = []
  
for i in range(11):
    # Append an empty sublist inside the list
    matrix.append([i])

    for j in range(6):
        matrix[i].append(i**j)
print(matrix)
```

I understand the geeks for geeks part. However, the list comprehension is confusing to me. Why and How does

```
[i] + [i**j..]]
```

`[i]` append/prepend to the list instead of resulting in `[[0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]`?

Does the `+` function as `listA.extend(listB)`?

Comment: Have you tested what happens when you do `[0] + [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I don't know why that didn't occur to me, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List comes under sequence class and sequence provide a method of concatenation
similar to your concatenation in your string .

by concatenation

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=[2,3,4]
c=a+b
c=[1,2,3,2,3,4]
```